# Can I use Cygwin with Windows-native-only terminal apps?

Tags: windows, command-line, terminal, cygwin

I use a Cygwin on Windows relatively often. However - the Cygwin terminal app, mintty.exe, is... well, underwhelming. It has repaint issues, resizes don't always get communicated like I would expect etc.

Then there are all sorts of terminal applications you can use on Windows, with examples such as, well, Windows Terminal, but also cmd.exe (which isn't that great either), PuTTY and others.

I was wondering whether I can run a Cygwin shell somehow from within other popular Windows terminal apps.

Comment: `shopt -s checkwinsize` should solve the resize issue. You can add it to `.bashrc`

Comment: @matzeri: There isn't one single resize issue, but thanks for the tip. How come it's not in .bashrc by default, I wonder?

Comment: @einpoklum : I didn't have any issues with mintty so far, but if you find a bug, I suggest thta you open a bug report at the mintty web site. The maintainer is very supportive. Aside from this, ConEmu also seems to well with Cygwin, though I haven't used it a lot. Another good one is simply called [`Console`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

Comment: @einpoklum : The `.bashrc` is for user-specific configuration. There is no **default** file of this name. You could wonder, why this is not the default in an _interactive bash_. You could place a change request for the bash developers to introduce this change. If they reject it, they will at least let you know why they decided to implement it in the way it currently is.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your `bash.exe` (e.g. `C:\Path\To\Cygwin64\bin\bash.exe`) from within `cmd.exe` or a Windows Terminal session. But this won't initialize almost anything, and you won't even have access to your `/usr/bin` binaries. Instead, you could run:

```
C:\Path\To\Cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login
```

and that seems to result in a mostly-working environment. This will work with cmd.exe, Windows Terminal, and probably anything that can take a local command-line.

---

More specifically, in Windows Terminal, you can create a special profile for your Cygwin shell:

1. Start Windows Terminal.
2. On the top bar, click the "v" symbol and choose Setting
   (or alternatively type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>).
3. In the Profiles section, click "Add a New Profile".
4. Duplicate some profile (e.g. Powershell)
5. In the General profile settings tab, set:

   - Name: Cygwin Bash
   - Command-line: C:\Path\To\Cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --login
   - Starting Directory: %USERPROFILE%  (I think this shouldn't matter much)
   - C:\Path\To\cygwin64\Cygwin.ico
   - Tab Title: Cygwin Shell
6. Press Save.

Caveat: I've not spent enough time making sure this combination behaves close enough to how a terminal app + bash session behaves on a Linux desktop.

Comment: The `Cygwin.bat` script which is part of the Cygwin installation also gives the option `-i` to `bash`. This option enforces interactive mode for bash. I am not sure if there could be cases when this option is necessary (login bash without other options should be interactive anyway) but I use `-i` just to be sure.